# How do I fix this compile issue that I'm having with GLFW under Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: c++, glfw, glad

So I am trying to compile a basic application and when i try and compile it, it throws an error:

```
$ g++ -g -Iinclude -ldl -lX11 -lstdc++ src/*.cpp src/*.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glfw3 glib-2.0`
/usr/bin/ld: warning: librt.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJamhTZ.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    return 0;
}
```

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've downloaded the `glfw` and `glad` developer packages for `Ubuntu`? I am on `Fedora` and can't really say I've had problem with yours snippet. Here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libglfw3-dev_3.2.1-1_amd64.deb.html is apparently Ubuntu's `dev` package, but I suggest to see how to install the `dev` package for your distribution and respective version. 
[edit] I've compiled your snippet with: `g++ -o test main.cpp -I/usr/include/GLFW -lglfw` but removed the `#include<glad/glad.h>` since I don't have that library.

Comment: Yes i used apt to get glfw. Glad isnt even available as a package, it is downloaded from a web generator

Comment: Yes but is it glfw-devel or just glfw?

Comment: glfw3-dev and glfw3

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have glad I am using glew but later I will try to install glad and try your sample.

Comment: I've compiled your snippet with :
g++ -o test main.cpp -I/usr/include/GLFW -lglfw
but I've removed the #include <glad/glad.h> since I don't have it.